# Do Vimeo thumbnail URLs change?

Tags: thumbnails, vimeo

I've used the simple API to pull some video thumbnails from vimeo and I'm wondering if the urls for the thumbnails will ever change or are they permanent?

An example of the thumbnail I've got back was:

http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/253/951/253951971_200.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see now that Vimeo does not appear to change their thumbnails links.

Answer (score 2):

Vimeo just last week changed the structure of their thumbnail URLs, and before that it was different than when the question was asked, so it's safe to assume you can't presume they're stable long term.

We also asked their support about it, and their response was that they suggest we do not cache these URLs if possible.